# Most used bootrstrap CDN link/ links?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, panel

I was testing out using panels in my web app using this CDN link provided by the official [Bootstrap site](https://getbootstrap.com/)

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">`

The panels did not display after thorough checking of my code.

[image]

However I saw a similar post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997374/bootstrap-panel-is-not-working-properly) and the CDN link was different, which rendered the panels to show correctly.

`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

[image]

I thought all available boostrap links would contain the same bootstrap source, why isn't the official CDN link provided not working(for panels e.g)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have Bootstrap v4.3.1 in the first link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

you have bootstrap version 3.3.7 the second link

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: So bootstrap panels have been removed in version 4?

Comment: Cards are introduced, which do something similar